# Algorithm for reducing noise from signal data?

Tags: algorithm, average, sensors

I'm trying to write a program that smooths out some sensor data.

The sensor provides a threshold input 0 to 100. It is usually accurate within 2 units or so but is jumpy reading to reading.

I get input many times per second and would like to create dynamic average from this data that isn't so jumpy.

How would one go about averaging recent input in a way that you could get a smooth moving number, more accurate number (that keeps up in real-time with the readings) to show on an interface?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your data you can level the measured values by calculating an average.

- Using a certain number of previous results

  ```
  int values[BUFLEN];
  value = // your new raw measured value

  index = index++ % BUFLEN;
  values[index] = value;

  avg = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<BUFLEN; i++) {
      avg = avg + values[i] / BUFLEN;  // evenly weighted
  }
  ```

  You can use uneven weights, too, if you want to. Also, this loop can be optimized if you are using equal weights.
- Using a floating average

  ```
  avg = (avg * 0.9) + (value * 0.1)  // slow response
  avg = (avg * 0.5) + (value * 0.5)  // fast response

  float q = // new ratio
  avg = (avg * (1.0 - q)) + (value * q)  // general solution
  ```

The floating average (mathematically) is an weighted sum of all elements, where the weights are q<sup>N-i</sup> where `N` is the total measured values and `i` is the running index of the element. All elements are involved in the average, not just a limited number of elements.

You can check what is the frequency of the mistaken measures, what is the distance from the average, what response do you expect your (calculated) measures to follow the real processes, etc.

Also, if you have discrete values (integers), you have to be careful using the rounding thing. I recommend to do all calculations in floating point, then round the result to the nearest integer. But store the calculated average in floating point for the next round.

**Update:**

To reflect your question about being *up-to-date* and *accurate* at the same time:

The problem is that we are not sure whether the latest data is showing a tendency or is a result of an erroneous reading. I'll show you an example:

```
SEQ1: 15 15 14 15 15 [10]  6  6  5  6  6 
SEQ2: 15 15 14 15 15 [10] 20 15 14 15 15
```

So, what does `[10]` means in each sequence: In the first one, it represents a serious movement, a trend. In the second one, it is just a misread. But when you have just read `[10]`, you have no idea what will be the next one. So, you have to **delay** the effect of that read. So, it will not be *up-to-date*.

Similarly, you are using an average value, which is a **calculated** value. so, it won't be *accurate*.

It is a **balancing situation**. The more up-to-date the value is, the less accurate (more exposed to misreads). The more accurate your data is, the bigger the delay. Based on the data series, you have to choose it wisely.

I have calculated three scenarios for you, using the second (floating average) algorithm. The value of `q` is set to *lazy*, *normal* or *eager*.

```
SEQ1:     15    15    14    15    15    10     6     6     5     6     6 
// q=0.25, "lazy"
Avg       15.00 15.00 14.75 14.81 14.86 13.64 11.73 10.30  8.98  8.23  7.67
Rounded   15    15    15    15    15    14    12    10     9     8     7   

// q=0.5, "normal"
Avg       15.00 15.00 14.50 14.75 14.88 12.44  9.22  7.61  6.30  6.15  6.08
Rounded   15    15    15    15    15    12     9     7     6     6     6

// q=0.75, "eager"
Avg       15.00 15.00 14.25 14.81 14.95 11.23  7.31  6.33  5.33  5.83  5.96
Rounded   15    15    14    15    15    11     7     6     5     5     6
```

You can see that the *lazy* calculation still have not reached to `6` after 5 iteration, maybe 3 more is needed.

The *normal* was almost not error-prone, (14.5 was just rounded up), but could follow the trend almost immediately.

The *eager* was eagerly following the measures, adding just a slight alleviation to the curve. It could not even detect the 15-14-15 erroneous read.

The best value *for the series above* would be around `0.4` - `0.45` I think. It is worth to play around with a sample of *your real measurement data* to see what is the behavior of what parameter value.

Actually my favorite is **floating average** algorithm, it's easy to implement and gives a good result (if parameterized well).

Comment: Thanks, this is a good pointer in the right direction. BUFLEN = buffer length, or the number of historic values i want to use?

Comment: Yes, I added the definition.

Comment: what I recommend is to play around with some sample data, see what will you get with which algorithm and what parameter (BUFLEN, q).

Comment: Which algorithm have you chosen finally? Please don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This will lead to very smooth results - even if the values go up and down a lot during this time, this could just show a straight line. This will show the change in average over time. If this is not desired, this answer is probably not what you want.

Let's say we average over the last `k` input values.

The first thing to note is that:

```
Average at time i = (value[i] + value[i-1] + ... + value[i-k+1]) / k
                  = value[i]/k + value[i-1]/k + ... + value[i-k+1]/k

and

Average at time i-1 = value[i-1]/k + value[i-2]/k + ... + value[i-k+2]/k

thus, cancelling out common terms...

Average at time i = Average at time i-1 + value[i]/k - value[i-k+2]/k
```

And, to avoid potential rounding problems, keep the division by `k` out of this - just do it when you get the average (doing this doesn't invalidate the maths).

So, on to the algorithm:

- Have a circular array of size `k`. Initialize all values in this array to 0.
- Keep a count of the number of populated elements (initialized to 0).
- Whenever you insert into this buffer, update the average as follows:
  `average = newValue - overriddenValue`
  And increase the count if it's less than `k`.
- When getting the average for display purposes, just divide it by the count.